# Is this likely to be asbestos?

Tags: appliances, oven, stove, asbestos

I found this inside the electric stove/oven. I think it's a layer for heat insulation. The texture resembles cotton with shiny visible fibres. Question: is this likely to be asbestos?

[image: Cotton-like insulation material]

[image: Back side of the electric stove]

Comment: Looks too new. How old is it?

Comment: Even if it is asbestos, really need a test to confirm, unless sticking it into your nose for years it probably is okay.  Don't tell lawyers I said that, but your doctor will probably say the same thing.

Comment: If in USA, they stopped using asbestos long before the yellow+green grounding wire convention; they were bare/enameled copper before that.

Comment: @popham Not sure. This belonged to the previous owner of this house.

Comment: That anti-tipping sticker relates to a requirement introduced in 1988, so I place its manufacture date after 1988. Asbestos was banned from new products in 1989.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like fiberglass.  Asbestos usually looks dull and dirty.